# Sync file system changes in a folder to server on LAN (via SSH or NFS) automatically

Tags: macos, ssh, sync, nfs, mirroring

I'm looking for a solution that'll automatically sync file system changes in "/folder1" to "/folder2". Any change should be synced (deleted files, new folders etc.) without any confirmation. Preferably the changes will happen to "/folder2" instantly.

"/folder1" is on my hdd
"/folder2" is on a server on the LAN (can be accessed via SSH or NFS)

I'm on OS X 10.6.

I can't seem to find just the right tool. Does anyone

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use services such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for this. If your files and changesets are rather small, this might be the easiest solution. Newer versions might even have local sync, which would make your storage requirements your only limit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could combine [IWatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) to watch for changes, and have it run [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) in batch/silent mode on each change?

Answer (score 0):

There are open source solutions for file synchronization.
[lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) and [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) might be what you are looking for.